# ui-bootstrap modal appendTo

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the ui-bootstrap modal with angular to attach a modal to my document. However, I want the modal to be attached in a child div of the body with an id of #base-view. This is so that the modal will not affect the header on my page. I have a couple questions:

1) Is what I'm trying to do possible, or will modals always fade out the entire document

2) If it is possible, could someone point out the error in my ways

Code:

```
vm.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: config.TEMPLATES_URL + "reminders.template.html",
            controller: 'RemindersModalController',
            appendTo: angular.element(document.querySelector("#base-view"))
        });
```

This code exists in a component that is used in the base html page.

When this code is run, the modal does appear, but upon inspecting element it is still a child of the body div and not of the #base-view div.

I also am wondering if in fact the #base-view is part of the dom when all of this is called.

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: Not at the moment, this was placed into the 'wishlist' category as more pressing things came up. I hope to work on it in the next 2 weeks

Answer (score 2):

I'm using version **0.14.3** of ui-bootstrap and tried to use the appendTo-attribute with the uib-modal. I didn't have any success so i finally debugged a little bit and recognized that the appendTo-Option is **not implemented** in this version of ui-bootstrap. I don't know if other versions do.
Just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you just increase z-index value of the header?

Answer (score -2):

for child element just add `display:block`